# Do not show Onboarding activity again on button click

Tags: java, android

I have a Android App built in Android studio, on this app, I am using a Walkthrough Activity.

How can set this activity in a way that when a button is clicked, this page won't show again.

This is the function "public void onFinishButtonPressed()" and this is the part where I added onlick listener to the button, how should it be done in a way that once this function is called, this activity will not open again.

I have tried to implement a code to show activity only on first time run, but it is still not the desired result, i really want this page to keep showing until using clicks on that button.

Thanks for your help in advance.

My code;

```
package com.frigate.vpn.view;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.frigate.vpn.R;
import com.shashank.sony.fancywalkthroughlib.FancyWalkthroughActivity;
import com.shashank.sony.fancywalkthroughlib.FancyWalkthroughCard;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Walkthrough extends FancyWalkthroughActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FancyWalkthroughCard fancywalkthroughCard1 = new FancyWalkthroughCard("Welcome to Frigate Media VPN", "Let me show you why so many people love Frigate Media VPN", R.drawable.find_restaurant1);
        FancyWalkthroughCard fancywalkthroughCard2 = new FancyWalkthroughCard("We Protect your Privacy", "Internet access is mind free, we'll keep you safe",R.drawable.pickthebest);
        FancyWalkthroughCard fancywalkthroughCard3 = new FancyWalkthroughCard("Fast & Limitless!", "We provide you the fastest servers without limits.",R.drawable.chooseurmeal);
        FancyWalkthroughCard fancywalkthroughCard4 = new FancyWalkthroughCard("Frigate Media VPN is 100% Free", "You do not have to worry about paying for expensive VPN, we give you everything for free.",R.drawable.mealisonway);

        fancywalkthroughCard1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
        fancywalkthroughCard1.setIconLayoutParams(300,300,0,0,0,0);
        fancywalkthroughCard2.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
        fancywalkthroughCard2.setIconLayoutParams(300,300,0,0,0,0);
        fancywalkthroughCard3.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
        fancywalkthroughCard3.setIconLayoutParams(300,300,0,0,0,0);
        fancywalkthroughCard4.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
        fancywalkthroughCard4.setIconLayoutParams(300,300,0,0,0,0);
        List<FancyWalkthroughCard> pages = new ArrayList<>();

        pages.add(fancywalkthroughCard1);
        pages.add(fancywalkthroughCard2);
        pages.add(fancywalkthroughCard3);
        pages.add(fancywalkthroughCard4);

        for (FancyWalkthroughCard page : pages) {
            page.setTitleColor(R.color.black);
            page.setDescriptionColor(R.color.black);
        }
        setFinishButtonTitle("Get Started");
        showNavigationControls(true);
        setColorBackground(R.color.white);
        //setImageBackground(R.drawable.restaurant);
        setInactiveIndicatorColor(R.color.grey_600);
        setActiveIndicatorColor(R.color.colorGreen);
        setOnboardPages(pages);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishButtonPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Walkthrough.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use a global boolean variable named "isFinishedButtonPressed" set to false by default and when the button is pressed set it to true, and with the correct conditions it should do what you want, no ?

Comment: that would not work because that's not persistent storage.